# The area of a triangle determined by two diagonals at a vertex of a regular heptagon

Tags: geometry

> In a circle of diameter 7, a regular heptagon is drawn inside of it. Then, we shade a triangular region as shown:
>
> [image]
>
> What’s the exact value of the shaded region, without using trigonometric constants?

My attempt

I tried to solve it with the circumradius theorem : $A=(abc)/(4R)$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the three sides, and $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle. However, I needed to find the exact value of $\cos(5\pi/14)$, $\cos(4\pi/7)$, and $\sin(5\pi/14)$. Finally, I found an explicit formula for this particular triangle, but the proof was missing.

You can find the formula in Wikipedia's ["Heptagonal triangle" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagonal_triangle).

Comment: The OP is being coy for some reason, but the area given in the link is $\dfrac{\sqrt 7}{4}r^2$, where here we have $r=\frac72$.

Comment: @user I am going to write a solution using complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you, @JeanMarie, user and Quanto. All of your proofs teach me new ways of thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressing the sides $a,b,c$ via the sines of corresponding central angles one obtains:
$$
A=\frac{abc}{4R}=2R^2\sin\frac\pi7\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{4\pi}7.\tag1
$$

For a product of sines we have the following theorem:
$$
\prod_{0<m_i<n}2\sin\frac{\pi m_i}{n}=n.
\tag2
$$

Therefore: $$2^6\sin\frac\pi7\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}7\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}\sin\frac{5\pi}7\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}=\left(8\sin\frac\pi7\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{4\pi}7\right)^2=7.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof using complex numbers geometry : Let

$$\zeta=\exp(2i \pi/7).$$

For the sake of simplicity, we will work in a heptagon inscribed in a unit circle.

The vertices of the triangle can be considered as being

$$1, \ \ \ \zeta^2, \ \ \ \zeta^3$$

Using the (oriented) area formula one can find in [one of my recent answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2018125), we get :

$$A = -\frac{1}{4i}\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & \bar{1} \\ 1 & \zeta^2 & \bar{\zeta}^2 \\ 1 & \zeta^3 & \bar{\zeta}^3 \end{vmatrix}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4i}\left(-(\zeta-\bar{\zeta})-(\zeta^2-\bar{\zeta}^{-2})+(\zeta^3-\bar{\zeta}^{-3})\right)$$

$$=-\frac{1}{4i} \ 2i \ \left(-\sin \frac{2\pi}{7}-\sin \frac{4\pi}{7}+\sin \frac{6\pi}{7}\right)=-\frac12 \left(-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)$$

(see for example [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1697704p10891928)), or alternatively take the imaginary part of relationship

$$1+2(1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4)=\sqrt{7}i$$

see lemma 1 p. 128 of this very interesting [document](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2009volume9/FG200912.pdf), involving Gauss sums. This document is especially interesting because it displays many sides of heptagonal triangles using complex geometry. For Gauss sums, see as well this question and its [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279748).

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to

$$I= \sin\frac\pi7  \sin\frac{2\pi}7 \sin\frac{3\pi}7= \frac{\sqrt7}8
$$

Let $a =\frac\pi7$ and evaluate
\begin{align}
I^2 & = (1-\cos^2 a )  (1-\cos^2 2a )  (1-\cos^2 3a )\\
 & =\frac18 (1-\cos 2a )  (1-\cos 4a )  (1-\cos 8a )\\
 & =\frac18 (1-\cos 2a \cos 4a \cos 8a )\tag1\\
\end{align}

where the following equality via $2\cos x\cos y= \cos(x+y)+ \cos(x-y)$ is used

\begin{align}
\cos 2a \cos 4a + \cos 4a \cos 8a+ \cos 8a \cos 2a
 =\cos 2a +\cos 4a + \cos 8a\\
\end{align}
Note that

$$\cos 2a \cos 4a \cos 8a= \frac{\sin4a \cos 4a \cos 8a}{2\sin 2a}
= \frac{\sin16a}{8\sin 2a}=\frac18
$$

Thus, (1) yields

$$I = \sqrt{\frac18(1-\frac18)}= \frac{\sqrt7}8$$